# Access Update Query Showing Popup

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have Two tables T_S_Table_1 and Temp.

The T_S_Table_1 has a field XX_Country (Value & Key). This field is a Short text.
Temp has a field Update this is also short text.

I am unable to to run an update query to update all the values in this field to the Temp table.

I am using the query design in MSAccess design view.
Update to value i am using is `[T_S_Table_1]![XX_Country (Value & Key)]`

When i click run it gives me a popup with 'enter parameter value'.
Here is the sql statement it generated.

`UPDATE Temp SET Temp.[Update] = [T_S_Table_1]![XX_Country (Value & Key)];`

Any help on why is this occurring?

Comment: Does Temp already have records and you are trying to UPDATE specific field? How should the query know which records to update with which source values? Tables must have a relationship and be joined in query. Perhaps you really need an INSERT SELECT action. But why copy all records to another table? Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Temp is an empty table with only one column. I am trying to add left function to the query before inserting but however this update query is not working to move forward. and it has only one field, this i have created for testing purpose. The naming convention comes with the file unfortunately which i have no control over. this works when the table names doesn't have any spaces or special chars, any workaround?

Comment: I tested without spaces and special chars and still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax to remove popup:
`UPDATE Temp, T_S_Table_1 SET [Update] = [XX_Country (Value & Key)];`
However, results will not be satisfactory.

UPDATE is wrong action. Use INSERT INTO SELECT and it works.

`INSERT INTO Temp([Update]) SELECT [XX_Country (Value & Key)] FROM T_S_Table_1`

If you need to first delete records from Temp:

`DELETE FROM Temp`

Comment: Thanks a Lot - I was supposed to use append instead of Update. the second solution works.